# Database count is returning Undefined

Tags: javascript, return, return-value, velo

I need small help in a small code. The function is returning `[object Promise]` and I want to return the count.
When I use console.log within the function it works perfectly fine and shows the appropriate result, however when returning the code and use console.log outside the function it is saying `[object Promise]`.

```
async function queryDB(num) 
{
    await wixData.query("numDB")
    .eq("nums", num)
    .find()
    .then( (results) => 
    {
        var  count = results.items.length
        console.log("count in function: " + count)
        return count
    })
    .catch( (err) => 
    {
        let errorMsg = err;
    } );
}
```

Then I call it with:

```
$w.onReady(function () 
{
    var num1 = queryDB("1");
    console.log("count out function: " + num1)    
});
```

And I am getting the following output:

```
count out function: [object Promise]
count in function: 3
```

TIA

Comment: `onReady(async function () {`  & `var num1 = await queryDB("1")`

Comment: @Keith it returns undefined like that

Answer (score 0):

A few issues here..

1. Your queryDB doesn't return anything, apart from an undefined Promise
2. Your mixing thenables with async / await, do one or the other.
3. Your catch is doing nothing, generally speaking avoid catch, unless your trapping something specific, handle errors further up, not in util functions.

Since your using async/await..

```
async function queryDB(num) 
{
    const results = await wixData.query("numDB")
      .eq("nums", num)
      .find();
    var count = results.items.length
    console.log("count in function: " + count)
    return count;
}

$w.onReady(async function () 
{
    var num1 = await queryDB("1");
    console.log("count out function: " + num1)    
});
```

For completeness, if you were not using async / await.

```
function queryDB(num) 
{
    return wixData.query("numDB") //don'f forget to return
      .eq("nums", num)
      .find()
      .then(results => {
         var count = results.items.length
         console.log("count in function: " + count)
         return count;
      });
}

$w.onReady(function () 
{
    queryDB("1").then(num1 => {
      console.log("count out function: " + num1)    
    });
});
```